# Use cycles's denoiser on multi-layer EXRs

Tags: cycles-render-engine, denoise

The built-in denoiser that comes with Cycles in Blender 2.79 is awesome. Sadly, it's come too late to use in a current project... However, I have multi-layer EXRs containing all the render layers from Cycles for this project. Is there a way to feed these pre-rendered render layers through the Cycles denoiser? I couldn't find a node in the compositor to do this :(

This would also be really helpful when tuning the denoiser parameters. Currently, I have to wait for an entire render to complete to test any denoiser settings change. It's clear that the denoiser does run as a post-process (it has to wait until each tile has fully rendered before applying the denoising) so I feel there must be a way to feed in already rendered layers...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on B°WIDE nodepack:

https://bwide.wordpress.com/node-groups/bwide-nodepack-for-blender/

It has a **PassCombineDeNoiser**, that combines Cycles render passes & denoise it pass by pass based on Normals. You can also denoize exr-files, if you have all needed layers. It looks similar to new denoizer